# Getting the Javascript dropdown menu to work with ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just started my journey into programming, and don't understand a lot of things my most recent problem is trying to get a javascript dropdown menu to work with my ruby objects.

I currently have this code in my view

`<tr class="<%= inv.special %> <%= inv.hotel_id %>">`

and when i inspect the element this is what shows.

`<tr class="true 4" style="display: table-row;">`

This is what i have done with javascript but cant seem to get the inv.hotel.id to work. any help will be appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function(){
                            $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
                                    choice = $(this).text()


                                    id_of_hotel = $(this).attr('inv.hotel_id');

                                    if(choice == "Normal"){
                                        $("tr.false").show()
                                        $("tr.true").hide()
                                    }else if(choice == "Special"){
                                            $("tr.false").hide()
                                            $("tr.true").show()
                                        // else if(choice == "4"){
                                        //  $("tr.false" + id_of_hotel).show()
                                        //  $("tr.true" + id_of_hotel).hide()
                                        //  }
                                        // else if(choice == "2"){
                                        //  $("tr.false." + id_of_hotel).show()
                                        //  $("tr.true" + id_of_hotel).hide()
                                            }
                                    }

                                            $(this).closest(".dropdown").find(".btn").text(choice)

        // $(".btn").text($(this).text());
        // $(".btn").val($(this).text());
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what error do you get on the javascript console?

Comment: I hate to be _that_ guy, but, it looks like you are getting a few things confused. Namely: Server side/client side and what html classes/attributes are. The best advice I can give you is learn what these things are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe classes starting with numbers (or solely numbers) are not allowed in HTML. Either way, your javascript is trying to refer to an attribute called "inv.hotel_id" that doesn't exist, because you never specified the data to be linked to such a name on the client side. The only attributes in the element are `class` and `style`. A more elegant way of passing such data to javascript/jQuery would perhaps be using a `data-*` attribute. So, something like this:

```
<tr data-id="<%= inv.hotel_id %>">
```

Then if you want to reference that data-attribute, you may use `$(this).data("id")`.

You can still use the true/false classes because of the way you are using them to refer to the objects. Classes and id:s are good for selectors, but not for other miscellaneous data.